# pattern for changing key value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
[ 0 ] => 3000mAh battery
[ 1 ] => charges 1 smartphone
[ 2 ] => input: 5W (5V, 1A) micro USB port
[ 3 ] => output: Micro USB cable: 7.5W (5V, 1.5A)
[ 4 ] => recharge time 3-4 hours
[ 5 ] => includes Micro USB cable
[ 6 ] => 1-Year Limited Warranty
```

I want to remove these keys and put the part of the string that is already in value. The final result that i want is:

```
[ battery ] => 3000mAh 
[ charges ] =>  1 smartphone
[ input ] =>  5W (5V, 1A) micro USB port
[ output ] =>  Micro USB cable: 7.5W (5V, 1.5A)
[ recharge ] =>  time 3-4 hours
[ includes ] =>  Micro USB cable
[ Warranty ] => 1-Year Limited
```

There is three condition here:

1) if string have : then take text before first : and put it in key
example:

```
[ 2 ] => input: 5W (5V, 1A) micro USB port
[ input ] =>  5W (5V, 1A) micro USB port
```

2) if string begins with number take last word of string and put it like key:

```
[ 0 ] => 3000mAh battery
[ battery ] => 3000mAh
```

3) if string begins with letter take first word of string and put it like key:

```
[ 1 ] => charges 1 smartphone
[ charges ] =>  1 smartphone
```

This is my code that solved first condition, can you help me how i can do the rest?

```
$new_array= array_reduce($old_array, function ($c, $v){ 
            preg_match('/^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$/', $v, $m); 
            if(!empty($m[1])){
                return array_merge($c, array($m[1] => $m[2]));}
            else{
                return array();
            }
        },[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use regexes - just using `explode()` can break down the items quicker and also (IMHO) clearer.  This first looks to split it with `:`, if this produces a result, then use the first item as the key and the rest as the content.  If this fails then use a space and just check which version to use (using `is_numeric()` on the first character)...

```
$output = [];
foreach ( $data as $item )  {
    $split = explode(":", $item );
    if ( count($split) > 1 )   {
        $key = array_shift($split);
        $join = ":";
    }
    else    {
        $split = explode(" ", $item);
        if ( strtolower($split[count($split)-1]) == "warranty" ||
                is_numeric($item[0]) ){
            $key = array_pop($split);
        }
        else    {
            $key = array_shift($split);
        }

        $join = " ";
    }
    $output[$key] = implode($join, $split);
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: this is great! but in some cases i need one more condition.
if string begins with the letter and in that string is word warranty, put word warranty as a key name

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual text and what you want out of it.

Comment: Lifetime Warranty

Comment: using this code, it will put word Lifetime as a key, but warranty must always be a key

Comment: I've updated the code - the lines starting `if ( strtolower( $split[0] ) == "warranty" ) {` check if the next word is Warranty and adds this to the already extracted first word

Comment: this does not help, its still the same

String: Limited Lifetime Warranty

Comment: [Limited] => Lifetime Warranty
I've got this

Comment: This is why I asked for an example as I don't know all your requirements.  I will update it in a few minutes.

Comment: I've added code which will also do this for "1-Year Limited Warranty"

Comment: this also doesnt work [Limited Lifetime Warranty] =>

Comment: it show me like this [Limited Lifetime Warranty] =>

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: [Warranty] => Limited Lifetime

Answer (score 1):

You could check the first characters by using [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) or [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). To check for a `:` you could use explode and check if the count is greater than 1.

To write the value, you could use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with a space as the glue.

```
$result = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $res = explode(':', $item);
    if (count($res) > 1) {
        $key = $res[0];
        array_shift($res);
        $result[$key] = implode(':', $res);
        continue;
    }
    if (is_numeric($item[0])) {
        $parts = (explode(' ', $item));
        $key = array_pop($parts);
        $result[$key] = implode(' ', $parts);
        continue;
    }
    if (ctype_alpha ($item[0])) {
        $parts = explode(' ', $item);
        $key = array_shift($parts);
        $result[$key] = implode(' ', $parts);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CbnZN)

Comment: In the first `if()` you've split the text using `:` and then implode with ` ` (a space) which will remove any `:` from the text (as in `Micro USB cable: 7.5W (5V, 1.5A)`).  Also why do you use `continue` instead of having `elseif`?

Comment: @NigelRen That is correct, that should be a `:` instead. Thank you! I use `continue` because I imho I think it is an easier read without the `elseif`. But you could also write it with`elseif` of course https://3v4l.org/gRrhF

Comment: this is great! but in some cases i need one more condition. if string begins with the letter and in that string is word warranty, put word warranty as a key name

Comment: @doki You might do it like this, but beware what arrays can not have the same key https://3v4l.org/Zvi0X, so if warranty is in multiple lines that would not work. This solution takes only the first occurrence of warranty.